# How to create a new column in pandas using special condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Hi I have a dataframe in pandas like below,

| exit | new_column. |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0. |
| 0 | 0. |
| 0 | 0. |
| 1 | 1. |

I need to create the desired output column as given below,
in the exit column, if there are two occurances of 1 within next 10 rows, if so, sets the value of the new column for the current occurrence of 1 to 1 and to 0 for the later occurrence of 1. If there are no other occurrences of 1 in the next 10 rows, the new column is set to 1 for the current occurrence of 1. If the value of 'exit' is 0, the new column is set to 0.

| exit | new_column. | desired_output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

I tried the below code, but i am not able to acheive desired output column, i am acheiveing results similar to new_column which is not intended.

```
df['new_column'] = 0

for i, row in combined_df.iterrows():
    if row['exit'] == 1:
        next_rows = df.loc[i+1:i+10, 'exit']
        if (next_rows == 1).any():
            df.loc[i, 'new_column'] = 1
            later_occurrence_index = next_rows[next_rows == 1].index[0]
            df.loc[later_occurrence_index, 'new_column'] = 0
        else:
            df.loc[i, 'new_column'] = 1
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'new_column'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rolling`:

```
check_one = lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] == 1) & (x.sum() == 1)
df['out'] = (df[['exit', 'new_column']].eq(1).all(axis=1)
                                       .rolling(10, min_periods=1)
                                       .apply(check_one).astype(int))
print(df)

# Output
   exit  new_column  out
0     0           0    0
1     0           0    0
2     1           1    1
3     0           0    0
4     0           0    0
5     0           0    0
6     0           0    0
7     0           0    0
8     1           1    0
```